# Titanium: ImageViews with remote images not showing as Retina

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Using SDK 3.5.1 currently

I have some remotely hosted images that I am loading into my ImageViews. I have hires:true already set.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var hasattachesThumbIcon = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                width:96,
                height:'auto',
                top:6,
                bottom:6,
                right:10,
                image:hasattachesThumb,
                defaultImage:'/icons/placeholder_big.png',
                hires:true,               
      });
```

I think the issue is that I'm not explicitly setting the height of the image. The reason is that the images are of all different sizes and aspect ratios, my only requirement is that they should fit into a block measuring 96 pixels, so i've set it as such.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the height to `Ti.UI.SIZE`? `'auto'` is considered depracated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test 2X or 3X images? If you are trying 3X images then hiRes will not work as the support is still not present. Also as suggested by Mark, change from auto to Titanium.UI.SIZE, as auto has been deprecated. Also can you confirm whether the default image is getting displayed till the remote image is being downloaded?